# the type or namespace name 'Management' does not exist in the namespace 'MicrosoftSqlServer' are you missing an assembly reference

Tags: c#, .net

I am using:

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
```

I am using the above namespaces for restore database from `c# window form`, but the compiler tell me

> The type or namespace name 'Management' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'MicrosoftSqlServer' are you missing an assembly reference

And I follow some advice from Google,  found the `DLL` in  `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies`:

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll;
Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll
```

and I copy them and paste them to all the location in my project, but I still have error message from compiler.

Could anyone where I can put the reference to?

Comment: Add references to the needed assemblies

Answer (score 13):

I "fixed" this by reinstalling SqlServer Scripting through the Nuget console:

```
>> Uninstall-Package Microsoft.SqlServer.Scripting

>> Install-Package Microsoft.SqlServer.Scripting
```

Comment: My problem was that the added references (that Resharper had taken care of) pointed to the GAQ. Worked on my machine but failed on the build server. It was fixed installing the Nuget package you mention so the build server knew where to get the dll's.

Comment: This had fixed issue for building in Jenkins but for building in Visual Studio 2013 (also works in Jenkins) I had to use "Install-Package Unofficial.Microsoft.SQLServer.SMO.2014 -Version 12.0.2000.8" as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36832965/c-sharp-smo-and-sqlenum-references-error/36833261#36833261

Comment: This worked for me, once I selected the correct Default project in the Package Manager Console. Thanks!

Comment: Note - these libraries are tied to SQL Server binaries v11.0.2100.61 ( SQL Server 2012), which may not work against future versions as features are updated. This is /not/ a Microsoft-released library. Nuget Ref: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Scripting/

Answer (score 2):

Dont manually copy the SQL Management DLLs to the project folder.

In Visual Studio, in the Project in Solution Explorer, right click References > Add.

Comment: What if there are no search results for `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management`?

Comment: Then you need to install them, probably easiest installing SQL Server, or in Visual Studio's installer select the data components.

Answer (score 1):

### Install SMO from MS-issued NuGet Package

The [SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/overview-smo?view=sql-server-ver15) is a set of objects designed for programmatic management of Microsoft SQL Server and Microsoft Azure SQL Database.

Beginning with SQL Server 2017 SMO is distributed as the [`Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects` NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects) to allow users to develop applications with SMO. This means it's no longer necessary to install the Microsoft SQL Server SDK as a separate install.

To install SMO as a NuGet Package:

1. First, open that Package Manager Console. In Visual Studio:
   `Tools` ⯈ `NuGet Package Manager` ⯈ `Package Manager Console`
2. Use the console to install the `Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects` NuGet package:

   `Install-Package Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects`

Now, the SMO references are available as package references (Expand *References* for the given project):

[image: Project SMO refefences]

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using any workarounds, I found the root cause of my issue: I had a bad download of the SQL Server ISO. I confirmed that by double-checking SHA1 hash (74279286C2ABFBA9E9FF6DBEE60B71669BD234D2) of the downloaded file.

After re-downloading and re-installing, my project worked as expected.

Extra info: [Finding Checksum Values in Windows 10](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/finding-checksum-values-in-windows-10/dbc3c569-4b5a-4967-8810-c25255cdc1fd)

I used PowerShell:

```
Get-FileHash -Path .\en_sql_server_2016_developer_with_service_pack_2_x64_dvd_12194995.iso -Algorithm SHA1
```