# The type or namespace name 'Management' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.SqlServer' - SqlParser and VSTS automated builds

Tags: c#, sql-server, parsing, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using the Parser that is part of `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser.Parser` namespace in order to parse a Sql statement and it works fine when testing, however; the build fails in VSTS with the following error:

> Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Management' does not exist
>   in the namespace 'Microsoft.SqlServer' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)

I have referenced the library by adding a reference to `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser` using the add reference context and selecting Extensions.

I have the following import

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser.Parser;
```

and am executing the Parser

```
var rst = Parser.Parse(sqlStr);  
return Json(rst.Errors, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

I am assuming I need additional libraries in order to build in VSTS but am not sure which? Perhaps these libraries does not build on VSTS? Please assist with a solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting SQL server 2017, then you will need to include the [SMO NuGet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/installing-smo?view=sql-server-2017) package in your project.

Otherwise you will need to install the SharedManagementObjects.msi from the Feature Pack of the SQL server version and service pack level you are targeting or referencing.

[SQL Server 2016 SP2 Feature Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56833)
[SQL Server 2014 SP2 Feature Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53164)
[SQL Server 2012 SP4 Feature Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56041)

Comment: The solution builds and runs fine on my Dev PC with or without installing the SMO package. The problem is that it does not build on VSTS.

Comment: Do you have SQL Server Management Studio installed on your Dev PC? If the answer is yes, then SMO was already installed when you installed SQL Server Management Studio.