# C# SMO and SqlEnum references error

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, smo

I am doing a C# project by `VS2013` which is using `smo` object.
I installed

```
Install-Package Microsoft.SqlServer.Scripting
Install-Package Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum.dll
```

by `Nuget`

and included

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Agent;
```

but getting the following error

> Error 9   Assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' uses
>   'Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' which has a higher version than
>   referenced assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum, Version=10.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'

any hand?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is version mismatch between *Smo* and *SqlEnum* component, as the exception specifies. 
The problem is that the package, you have used `Install-Package Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum.dll` is an older package for SQL Server 2008.

There are folders containing the neccessary DLL files `(Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum.dll, Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll, Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll)` in your SQL Server installation folder:

- SQL Server 2012 
  `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies`
- SQL Server 2014,2016 
  `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies`

You can install all DLLs that you need also from Nuget in one package:

2012: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unofficial.Microsoft.SQLServer.SMO/

2014: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unofficial.Microsoft.SQLServer.SMO.2014/

> Included DLLs: **Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll**,
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfoExtended.dll,
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll,
>   **Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll**, Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended.dll,
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlClrProvider.dll,
>   **Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum.dll**

You should either use `Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum.dll` & `Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll` file from that `SDK\Assemblies` folder that you have used when creating reference to `Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo`. Or you should install matching assemblies from NuGet. Version 11.0.0.0 of DLLs stands for SQL Server 2014.

See [Files and Version Numbers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162161.aspx) and [Create a Visual C# SMO Project in Visual Studio .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162129%28v=sql.130%29.aspx).

If you install only one correct package from NuGet like https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unofficial.Microsoft.SQLServer.SMO.2014/, you should be OK.

Comment: This can also happen if you're using .NET Core but referencing the packages as if they're NetStandard compliant.