# Reference.svcmap: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum,

Tags: c#, sql-server, host

when I upload the website on the host below error accrue I don't have any problem in localhost but when I upload it on a host this error accrues:

Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Reference.svcmap: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error:

[No relevant source lines]

Source File: /App_WebReferences/XMLForSMSServiceReference1/    Line: 1

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' could not be loaded.

what should I do?
Best Regards
Neda

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of : [C# SMO and SqlEnum references error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36832965/c-sharp-smo-and-sqlenum-references-error/36833261)

Short answer is the binaries you are deploying on to target server are missing referenced binaries (I am guessing the Sql server SMO library).

When you deploy a project to the destination you have to ensure the destination has the shared components (such as SQL SMO) already installed there, if not you have to include such shared binaries through your msi/deployment.

In your case there are two possible workarounds depending upon how you want to achieve it.

1. Create the msi and include all binaries (including the once those go in global cache - strongly signed libraries) - this is the more sensible way of handling *standard* deployment scenarios.
2. Only deploy your project binaries but ensure the referenced packages are already installed on destination.

Comment: hi I refer this link  C# SMO and SqlEnum references error but there was pakage for sqlserver 2014 I need pakage for sql2019 and didn't find any thing in NuGet